# How to undo echo deb package repository?

Tags: package-management, deb

I did a

```
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
```

on a Ubuntu 16.04 Linux Server on Azure to add `MongoDb` on Linux Server, that gave me `Failed to Fetch 404 Not found` during `apt-get update`. Now, I found that I had to use this for `mongodb` repo on 16.04

```
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list
```

How should I undo that previous listing so that I can do `apt-get update` again?

Comment: This will work  `sudo rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list`

Comment: Simply remove it as @Rahul has suggested, then `sudo apt update` Please Rahul put that in an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your first command:**

```
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
```

This will create a file `mongodb-org-3.0.list` in directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

If this is causing some problem then simplest solution is to simple remove it.

```
sudo rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
sudo apt-get update
```

**Safe solution:**

Files in `sources.list.d` are important so it is good practice to make a backup instead of completely removing it. Make a backup in case you need it in future (you never know).

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list.bak
sudo apt-get update
```